# Find the index of many values from a list

Tags: python, indexing

i wanted to find the index of many values from a list. Here i give a simple example:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
list2 = [3,5,6,7]
for a in zip(list2):
    id = list1.index(a)
print(id)
```

the expected output is:
[2, 4, 5, 6]

but instead of that, i got this:
ValueError: (3,) is not in list

if i tried this one:

```
id= list1.index(3)
print(id)
```

i got the right output: 2

So, does anyone see the problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Refrain from using keyword `id` as variable, this is asking for trouble.

Comment: Why do you `zip` `list2`?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `pandas` pls don't spam tags

Answer (score 1):

Your code work if you remove "zip"

```
print("stackoverflow")
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
list2 = [3,5,6,7]

tab = []
for a in list2:
    id = list1.index(a)
    tab.append(id)
print(tab)
```

result :

```
[2, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a list comprehension:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
list2 = [3,5,6,7]
res = [list1.index(x) for x in list2 if x in list1]
print(res)
```

result:

```
[2, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use list comprehensions

```
[list1.index(i) for i in list2 if i in list1]
```